# Application that lists all builds made from hudson

Tags: java, svn, version-control, continuous-integration, jira

Hello guys i'm looking for an application (or hudson plugin) that had simple list of all builds (made in hudson) including version number and jira info?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Marvelution JIRA plugin](http://docs.marvelution.com/display/MARVJIRAHUDSON/Documentation+Home).  If that doesn't meet your needs, amybe you could add some more details on what you're looking for.